# Bulk Insert Czech characters

Tags: sql-server, bulkinsert, collation

I got a tab delimited text file (cznames.txt)with PersonID and Names with Czech characters in it.
I am figuring out how to load it SQL Server table. Here's what I did

```
USE myDatabase
Go
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[myNameTable](
  [ID] smallint NOT NULL,
  [NAME] [nvarchar](50) collate Czech_CI_AS
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

I then created format file

```
bcp myDatabase.dbo.myNameTable format nul -c -f "C\temp\Czech.fmt" -T -Smyserver -Umyuser -P1mypwd
```

I used the below statement to insert into table

```
 BULK INSERT myDatabase.dbo.myNameTable FROM  'C:\temp\cznames.txt'
        WITH (FormatFile = 'C:\temp\Czech.fmt', FIRSTROW = 2, ROWTERMINATOR = '0X0A');
```

I find no errors but the characters in the table look very different from the text file.

Sample cznames.txt

```
ID  NAME
1   Vysočina
2   Olomoucký
3   Středočeský
4   Hlavní město
```

Here's the format file

```
10.0
2
1       SQLCHAR             0       7       "\t"     1     ID          ""
2       SQLCHAR             0       100     "\r\n"   2     Region      Czech_CI_AS
```

Can anyone help me

Thanks

Comment: It looks different when compared to the input text file

Comment: And what does your format file look like?

Comment: While asking a question, you need to provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example):
(1) DDL and sample data population, i.e. CREATE table(s) plus INSERT T-SQL statements. 
(2) What you need to do, i.e. logic and your code attempt implementation of it in T-SQL. 
(3) Desired output, based on the sample data in the #1 above.
(4) Your SQL Server version (SELECT @@version;).

Answer (score 0):

Please try the following solution.

The `CODEPAGE = '65001'` setting was a remedy.

> Versions prior to SQL Server 2016 (13.x) don't support code page 65001
> (UTF-8 encoding).

And without a format file.

**SQL**

```
USE tempdb;
GO

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS dbo.myNameTable;

CREATE TABLE dbo.myNameTable(
  ID INT NOT NULL,
  NAME NVARCHAR(50) collate Czech_CI_AS
);

BULK INSERT dbo.myNameTable 
FROM  'e:\Temp\cznames.txt'
WITH 
(
    FIRSTROW = 2,
    FIELDTERMINATOR = '\t',
    ROWTERMINATOR = '0x0A',
    CODEPAGE = '65001'
);

SELECT * FROM dbo.myNameTable;
```

**Output**

```
+----+--------------+
| ID |     NAME     |
+----+--------------+
|  1 | Vysočina     |
|  2 | Olomoucký    |
|  3 | Středočeský  |
|  4 | Hlavní město |
+----+--------------+
```

Comment: Unfortunately, we are running older version of SQL server

Comment: What version? `SELECT @@VERSION;`

Comment: sql server 2008

Comment: In such case you can use SSIS. It does support UTF-8 since it's inception in 2005